# How do i compare two unknow Variblabes in a list?

Tags: python, list, compare

Im trying to compare the 2 leftover varsables in this list and check if they are equel. But I want it to be reuseable so that you can change te Parameters to any number you want but to still work. But i couldnt figgure out how.

```
def max3( x , y , z ):
    AllParameters = [ x , y , z ]
    Biggestnumber = max( AllParameters )
    AllParameters.remove( Biggestnumber ) 


max3( 8 , 5 , 5)
```

I was searching online for quit a while but couldnt find a solution.

The output id like to achiev is that the programm is compareing the two left over vars in the list, after the biggest one was removed, if they are equel and then print out sth like "BiggestNumber" is biggest number and "LeftoverVars" are equel if they are equel. Depending on the Parameters

Comment: what is the expected output/result ? Please [edit] and add another example with "changing the parameters" so we're sure we understand well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the code reusable and compare the two remaining variables in the list.

```
def _max(x, y, z):
    all_parameters = [x, y, z]
    biggest_number = max(all_parameters)
    all_parameters.remove(biggest_number)
    remaining_variable1 = all_parameters[0]
    remaining_variable2 = all_parameters[1]
    return remaining_variable1 == remaining_variable2

result = _max(8, 5, 5)
print(result)
```

The two remaining variables in this modified code are given the names `remaining_variable1` and `remaining_variable2` after the `biggest_number` has been located. The function concludes by returning `True` if the two last variables are equal and `False` otherwise.

The code will output True in this case since the two remaining variables (5 and 5) are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
def max3(*args):

    all_parameters = list(args)
    biggest_number = max(all_parameters)
    all_parameters.remove(biggest_number)
    retu

rn all_parameters[0] == all_parameters[1]

result = max3(8, 5, 5)
print(result)  # Output: True
```

Comment: In this case, the max3 function uses the *args operator to take a variable number of arguments. The arguments are converted into a list called all_parameters. Then the largest number is found using the max function. Next, the largest number is removed from the list. Finally, a boolean value is returned indicating whether the two remaining numbers in the list are equal.

In the example above, max3(8, 5, 5) returns True since the two remaining numbers are both 5. You can modify the arguments passed to the max3 function to test different scenarios.